# Property Handler cannot be empty - The following resource(s) failed to create

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Am trying to create lamda function using cloudformation. While creating stack am getting error like below. I have pasted my template below. Please help me where am doing mistake.

> **20:01:50 UTC+0550   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  MyStack The
>   following resource(s) failed to create: [Lamdafuntion]. . Rollback
>   requested by user.
>
> 20:01:50
>   UTC+0550  CREATE_FAILED   AWS::Lambda::Function   Lamdafuntion    Property
>   Handler cannot be empty.**

**Template :**

```
"Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Description" : "Lambda Function",
                "Code" : {
                    "S3Bucket" : "awstier1bucket"
                    "S3Key" : "code.py.zip"
                },
                "FunctionName" : lambda_function 
                "Handler" : "test.lambda_handler",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "LambdaTest"
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: From your error message it seems there's another function definition which is missing a Handler property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's due to mismatch of function and handler name.
Generally it has to be constructed by combining file_name.function_name

I've tried the following and it worked:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "yeye",
  "Resources": {
    "my-resource-1": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "Lambda Function",
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::account_number:role/lambda_basic_execution",
        "Runtime": "python2.7",
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": "my_bucket",
          "S3Key": "**lambda_script**.py.zip"
        },
        "FunctionName": "my_function",
        "Handler": "**lambda_script.function_name**"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above I am uploading file named **lambda_script.py** which contains code with the following function defined:

```
def function_name(event, context):
    """
    code
    more code
    """
```

Which makes handler name **lambda_script.function_name**